# WPF datapoints custom style

Tags: c#, wpf, markers, lineseries, datavisualization.toolkit

I am creating a chart with some amount of lineseries on it(using DataVisualization toolkit), i am using such classes:

```
 private static Style ResultStylex()
    {
        Color background = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0);
        Style style = new Style(typeof(DataPoint));
        Setter st1 = new Setter(BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(background));
        Setter st2 = new Setter(HeightProperty, 8.8);
        Setter st3 = new Setter(WidthProperty, 8.8);

        style.Setters.Add(st1);
        style.Setters.Add(st2);
        style.Setters.Add(st3);

        return style;
    }
```

for every lineseries to change color and size of line and markers.
Is there any way to use such class(or alike) to make custom datapoint markers(such as triangle, square etc) without xaml modification? or somehow other way?

Something like point in [WPF Toolkit Chart: Positions of Data Point Visualization shifted when changing data values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924047/wpf-toolkit-chart-positions-of-data-point-visualization-shifted-when-changing-d) (o,>,M)

Comment: you mean - you want to create a new control such as triangle, square, etc.. ?

Comment: Yes, new contol to make datapoints(circles now) to be triangle, square...

Comment: something like point in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924047/wpf-toolkit-chart-positions-of-data-point-visualization-shifted-when-changing-d
(o,>,M)